# Add a border with cornerRadius to an Image in SwiftUI Xcode beta 5

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, beta, xcode11

how can I add a border with a `cornerRadius` to an Image. I get a deprecation warning saying that i should use a RoundedRectange Shape, but i don't know how to use that exactly

Beta 4:

```
Image(uiImage: ...)
   .border(Color.black, width: 2, cornerRadius: 10)
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

## SwiftUI 5.0

### Using clipShape & overlay Modifiers

Here is another way in which we can use a clipShape modifier (which clips the view) and then overlay a stroke with a color.

```
VStack(spacing: 40) {
    Text("Image Border").font(.largeTitle)
    Text("Using cornerRadius & overlay").font(.title).foregroundColor(.gray)
    Text("Using cornerRadius will also clip the image. Then overlay a border.")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .font(.title)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.orange)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    
    Image("profile")
        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 10))
        .overlay(.rect(cornerRadius: 10)
            .stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 4))
        .shadow(radius: 10)
}
```

### Result

[image: screenshot of clipshape]

Comment: What does the layoutPriority(1)?

Comment: It gives priority to assigning available space over other views within the same parent. (By default, the rest of the child views have a layoutPriority of zero.) Without this, that text view was only showing one line of text and getting truncated.

Comment: I can confirm this still works perfectly well with SwiftUI 2.0

Answer (score 31):

Consider this: adding a modifier to a view will return a new `View` instance that wraps the previous instance. This is also why the order in which you add modifiers matters.

We can use this to our advantage: by adding a padding, then adding a background to our new View, we can create our own additional layers:

```
Image("cat")
    .cornerRadius(7) // Inner corner radius
    .padding(5) // Width of the border
    .background(Color.primary) // Color of the border
    .cornerRadius(10) // Outer corner radius
```

Results in:

[image]

You can even turn this in a ViewModifier to be reusable more easily:

```
struct RoundedEdge: ViewModifier {
    let width: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.cornerRadius(cornerRadius - width)
            .padding(width)
            .background(color)
            .cornerRadius(cornerRadius)
    }
}
```

Using it would become:

```
Image("cat").modifier(RoundedEdge(width: 5, color: .black, cornerRadius: 20))
```

This workd for any SwiftUI View, like `Text`:

```
Text("Some text")
    .padding(15)
    .background(Color.red)
    .modifier(RoundedEdge(width: 5, color: .black, cornerRadius: 20))
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Compared to the accepted answer, this one uses `.padding` to avoid clipping of `Image` edges. Keep that in mind when deciding whether to add `.padding` depending on what you want to achieve visually.

Answer (score 15):

First, note that the way you were doing it, was not clipping the image. Maybe you did not noticed if the image was too small, or if it had a background of the same color of your canvas. But even while using your beta 4 syntax, you needed to add `.clipShape()`.

---

Back to your question, according to Beta 5 release notes:

> Complex overloads for the background(*:alignment:) and
>   border(*:width:) modifiers are deprecated. Use shapes in a
>   background(*:alignment:) or overlay(*:alignment:) to draw these
>   instead. (53067530)

So the pattern would be something like this:

```swift
.overlay(RoundedRectangle(...).stroke(...).foregroundColor(...))
```

In your specific case:

```swift
Image("mypic").resizable().frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).stroke(lineWidth: 2).foregroundColor(Color.black))
```

Comment: Thanks for considering clipping. Still having problems with this, but then I'm using a hosting controller from a UIViewController. I had to do the corner rounding and clipping from the UIViewController.

Comment: I think `.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))` is better than corner radius

Answer (score 8):

Write a rounded text view which is same with Image View

```
struct RoundedTextView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Rounded Text View")
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(16)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 8)
            )
    }
}
```

Preview like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I really liked kontiki's answer but not the length so I wrote:

```swift
import SwiftUI

func strokedRoundedRectangle(
        cornerRadius r: CGFloat,
        lineWidth w: CGFloat = 1,
        color c: Color = .primary
    ) -> some View {

    return RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: r).stroke(lineWidth: w).foregroundColor(c)
}
```

Comment: cornerRadius is also deprecated for background(). You can use the same RoundedRectangle expression but without the stroke()