# Add a circular image view with corner radius for an image in swiftUI

Tags: image, swiftui, shapes, cornerradius

How can I add a circular view similar to the attachment below. In the attachment, the check is the image icon and I want to add the green background color in circular shape. I have a solution in Swift but, couldn't implement the same in swiftUI.

Related posts to my question: [Add a border with cornerRadius to an Image in SwiftUI Xcode beta 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269651/add-a-border-with-cornerradius-to-an-image-in-swiftui-xcode-beta-5). But, this doesn't solve my issue.

**Swift code to this implemention:**

```
var imageView = UIImageView()
override init(theme: Theme) {
    super.init(theme: theme)
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    setLayout()
  }

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
    imageView.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius)
    setCornerRadius(cornerRadius)
  }
```

[image: CheckImage]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not the simplest thing to come up with. Use this struct as a separate view. It will return the image properly sized on the circle.

```
struct ImageOnCircle: View {
    
    let icon: String
    let radius: CGFloat
    let circleColor: Color
    let imageColor: Color // Remove this for an image in your assets folder.
    var squareSide: CGFloat {
        2.0.squareRoot() * radius
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(circleColor)
                .frame(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
            
            // Use this implementation for an SF Symbol
            Image(systemName: icon)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: squareSide, height: squareSide)
                .foregroundColor(imageColor)
            
            // Use this implementation for an image in your assets folder.
//            Image(icon)
//                .resizable()
//                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
//                .frame(width: squareSide, height: squareSide)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Yrb ! I used the `resizable()` property and now my images are correctly scaled to my parent `View`

Answer (score 25):

You could create this image like...

```
Image(systemName: "checkmark")
  .resizable()
  .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
  .foregroundColor(.white)
  .padding(20)
  .background(Color.green)
  .clipShape(Circle())
```

Or alternatively...

```
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
  .resizable()
  .frame(width: 40, height: 40) // put your sizes here
  .foregroundColor(.green)
```

Comment: Image doesn't have a modifier called backgroundColor, and for your second solution foregroundColor refers to the coloring the foreground elements. It had nothing to do with backgroundColor. None of your solutions works.

Comment: @Tejasree I made a couple of changes. I had written it all in the browser on my phone. But as for "none of your solution works". The code was 80% there with a couple of tweaks that most beginners would be able to find for themselves. And the second one worked with the addition of the word `Color` after foreground.

Comment: The alternative solution is missing the bracket after resizable. Shoud be `resizable()`